# How do I make this terminal script work properly?

Tags: terminal, script, command-line

I want it to appear like I'm contacting a bunch of ip-adresses and it works fine until the third line in the code and I want to be able to fix it. Also the 4 bottom lines don't work.

So this is basically what I've got so far:

```
for((i=0;i<=100000000;i++)); 
    do echo "Request #" $i " returned ip-adress " [$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256))];
  if["$i" = "100000000"]
    do echo "All ip-adresses have been stored in local hard drive." -$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256));
  if["$i" = "100000000"]
    do echo [Process Completed];
done
```

Comment: What are you even trying to do?  This doesn't store anything to the hard drive as is.  Simply saying fix this script for me won't work if no one can guess what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. You need whitespace between "if[" as well as "[numerical evaluation]” to execute properly.
2. The logical syntax is incorrect. `if` **x**; `then` (and only then) **y**; `else` **z**;`fi`;`done`. `Else` is not necessary, but you can’t declare two identical `if` statements like so:

   - `if` **x**, `then` **y**.
   - `if` **x**, `then` **z**.

That makes no logical sense. 
On the other hand:

- `if` **x**, `then` **y & z** does.

That said, here’s what you’re looking for:

```
#! /bin/bash

for((i=0;i<=100000000;i++)); 
    do echo "Request #" $i " returned ip-adress “[ $((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)) ];
if [ "$i" = "100000000" ];
    then echo "All ip-adresses have been stored in local hard drive." -$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)) && echo [Process Completed];
fi
done
```

Which, when saved as a script, `test.sh` returns the following:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ njboot$ test.sh
Request # 0  returned ip-adress  [ 0.84.37.68 ]
Request # 1  returned ip-adress  [ 169.181.247.217 ]
Request # 2  returned ip-adress  [ 164.183.119.15 ]
Request # 3  returned ip-adress  [ 191.149.177.224 ]
Request # 4  returned ip-adress  [ 84.28.26.92 ]
Request # 5  returned ip-adress  [ 54.38.89.138 ]
Request # 6  returned ip-adress  [ 86.222.217.2 ]
Request # 7  returned ip-adress  [ 57.178.16.75 ]
Request # 8  returned ip-adress  [ 26.22.140.245 ]
Request # 9  returned ip-adress  [ 222.255.194.118 ]
Request # 10  returned ip-adress  [ 188.26.150.197 ]
…
Request # 100000000 returned ip-adress  [ 233.66.114.134 ]
All ip-adresses have been stored in local hard drive. -181.167.202.102
[Process Completed]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you are trying to accomplish here, but doing a test for the exit condition while still being inside the loop isn't really necessary:

```
for ((i=0;i<=100000000;i++)); do
    echo "Request #$i returned ip-adress" [$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256))]
done

echo "All ip-adresses have been stored in local hard drive."
echo "[Process Completed]"
```

---

The syntax for `if ... then ... else` (in case you need this for something else) actually is

```
if [ $i -eq 100000000 ]; then
    echo "Got a match!"
fi
```